# Does the "face with tears of joy" emoji have an ASCII version or a Windows alt code?

Tags: ascii, alt-code, emoticons, emoji

Many emojis started as ASCII emoticons such as

:-)
:-(
:'(
:O
:P
;-(

etc.

In 2015, Oxford Dictionaries' "Word of the Year" was the emoji , known as the "face with tears of joy". Does this symbol have an ASCII version, in other words a string of ASCII characters that means the same as the emoji? Is there a Windows alt code for it?

Comment: Emojis were emoticons

Comment: There's a difference. I prefer to use plain-text email and emoticons in ASCII rather than the emoji images.

Comment: On Wikipedia, there are some listed under "Tears of happiness" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons#Western

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for "face with tears of joy" emoji is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>128514</kbd>. I tried it in Outlook and Word; they show the correct emoji. You can also use the <kbd>1F602</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

According to [Appendix:Emoticons](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Emoticons), its ASCII code is :'-)

[image]

[ALT Codes for Emoticons, Cat Faces & Gesture Symbols](https://altcodeunicode.com/alt-codes-emoticons-cat-faces-gesture-symbols/)

Comment: Thanks, but alt+128514 gives me the "black smiley face" in Word, the same as for alt+2. Is there a string of ASCII characters that even *means* "face with tears of joy"? (I will amend the question to ask that specifically.)

Comment: @ruffle What version of word are you using? Mine is 16.0.13029.20342. Have you tried 1F602+ALT+X?

Comment: @ruffle See edit

Comment: Word 11.5604.5606, aka Word 2003. When I type 1F602+ALT+X using the number pad for the digits, I get "0066" (i.e. it prints those four characters to the screen - weird!), but if I use the normal number keys above QWERTY I get the empty square which is Word's way of saying "can't print the desired character", although cutting and pasting to here gives  as required. Thanks for finding the :'-)

Comment: @ruffle I think (not 100% sure) that it is not displayed due to your version being old (before emojis became popular).